# How to disable git hooks in gitkraken?

Tags: githooks, git-extensions, gitkraken, husky

I'm working with a project that has git hooks configured. Unfortunately. It was added to prevent juniors or headless developers to commit CI-check-failing code to their branch.

I am one of these, who ignore git hooks with `HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS` env variable, but for me it doesn't work in GitKraken.

Do you know how to ignore git hooks in GitKraken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I did receive a response from their support, that works for me.

> Additionally, you should still be able to disable these hooks from executing. You will need to change the chmod permissions for the files, which reside under local_repo/.git/hooks.

`chmod -x .git/hooks/*`

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the command instruction like that `HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1 git <command> ...`?

You can use it like `HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=1` but also `HUSKY_SKIP_HOOKS=true`.

You can also bypass commit hooks in command line with : `git commit -m "bla bla" -n`.

If you'll be unable to run hooks for a long time, you also can use the core.hooksPath git configuration option:

```
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null checkout master
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null pull
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null commit ...
git -c core.hooksPath=/dev/null push
...
```

And (just sayin'), [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/) has an interface option to skip commit hooks. As far as I know Git Kraken doesn't have one.

[image: sourctree option to skip hooks]

Comment: The question is about GitKraken. You mention it briefly at the end, but the Git CLI instructions are not applicable.

Comment: @MEMark I know that, I just suggested other solutions because I was in the same case before and I didn't found other ways to fix my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly there doesn't seem to be a simple way to do this from the GitKraken. As others have pointed out you should pass in the Husky environmental variable normally. But here's a guaranteed simple solution that will always work. I'm currently using it to clean up some old repositories.

```sh
# Temporarily wipe husky
npm uninstall husky

# Clear out the husky package changes so we don't accidentally commit them
git reset --hard HEAD
```

When you're done in GitKraken re-install husky as so.

```sh
npm install
```